# create a text from a json response

Tags: json, node.js

I'm making an api call from my node js and getting a response in json. And below is my code.

```
apiServices.getCaseStatus("status", function(data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    if (data) {
                        console.log(`${data.length} is the length of the data returned`);
                    }
```

And the JSON that I get when I make the API call is as below.

```
[
  {
    "status_details": "requirements",
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
    "status_details": "requirements",
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
   "status_details": "forms",
    "status": "pending"
   },
  {
    "status_details": "decision",
    "status": "pending"
   }
]
```

Here I want a statement like below.

```
console.log(`${data.length} is the length of the data returned, 2 are pending requirements, 1 is pending decision, and 1 is pending forms`);
```

I am unable to know how I can get this type of result. please help me in doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd group them and count by `status_details`, then create your string from the object the `reduce` will return by mapping over its object keys

```js
let d = [{
    "status_details": "requirements",
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
    "status_details": "requirements",
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
    "status_details": "forms",
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
    "status_details": "decision",
    "status": "pending"
  }
];

let r = d.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b.status_details] = a[b.status_details] || {
    count: 0
  };
  a[b.status_details].count += 1;
  a[b.status_details].status = b.status;
  return a;
}, {});

let txt = [d.length + " is the length of the data returned", Object.keys(r).map(e => ' ' + r[e].count + (r[e].count > 1 ? ' are ' : ' is ') + r[e].status + ' ' + e)].join(', ');

console.log(txt);
```